# When referring to the convexity of a function, which preposition should I use before the argument?

Tags: terminology, convex-optimization

I want to express an arbitrary function is concave with respect to something. I read many journals related to the wireless communication and signal processing fields from the google scholar cite. Nonetheless, I couldn't grasp which preposition to use.

1. The data rate is a concave function of power allocation.
2. The data rate is a concave function for power allocation.
3. The data rate is a concave function with respect to power allocation.
4. The data rate is concave for power allocation.
5. The data rate is concave with respect to power allocation.

I have usually seen that the prepositions, *of*, *for*, and *with respect to* are used.
I've always passed by, but want to learn how to refer to clear mathematical terms in this opportunity.

If this question does not fit the nature of this bulletin board, please leave a comment.
I will delete this question myself. Thank you.

Comment: To me, both usages of "for" sound wrong, but all the others sound right.

Comment: @GregMartin Aside from "for" being wrong, is there no difference in meaning between the rest?

Comment: In my opinion, the rest are synonymous. I think I prefer #1 the most: "function of" is a pretty straightforward construction.

Comment: @GregMartin You gave me good assurance. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GregMartin May I ask you one more question?? If "of" is correct, is it possible to use the sentence "something is convex/concave of something"? Actually, I've seen "a convex/concave function of something" a lot, but I've never seen "be convex/concave of something" so far.

Comment: Good question: I would find "y is concave of x" strange. If I didn't want to say "function" but needed to specify the variable under discussion, I would probably use your #5 option.